# What is the correct word choice, "Consulting" or "Consultants'"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Attorney and Consulting Fees

or

Attorney and Consultants' Fees

Comment: could you provide some context?

Comment: this is a name of an account code for expense tracking

Comment: When someone asks for additional context, they are usually asking you to edit your question, not provide additional information in comments.

Comment: Consulting might be done by a legal assistant and you'd still pay for that service. Hence: Consulting Fees. A Consultant could be another legal professional like a lawyer, but not your specific attorney. A Consultant can also be  a medical professional. (A Consultant looks at the x-ray and makes her diagnosis.)

Answer (score 2):

"attorney" is a concrete noun, so for the sake of parallelism you should keep "consultant" (in the singular, without the genitive):

- **Attorney and Consultant Fees**

However, "attorney and consulting fees" seems to be used quite a lot. I wouldn't use it because, as I said above, "attorney" is a person, while "consulting" is an activity. Compare with "Legal and Consulting Fees," where *legal* and *consulting* seem to share the same semantic hierarchy.